# PXE Troubleshooting for SCCM 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, pxe-boot, wds, sccm-2012

I'm not able to PXE boot clients.

I get the following error: PXE-E55 ProxyDHCP Service did not reply to request on port 4011

This is a new setup of SCCM 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit). SCCM itself seems to be working, I can run OS deployment tasks from within the OS if the system is running the agent and that all installs OK.

If I attempt to PXE boot to install I get the PXE-E55 error mentioned above.

Server Manager says that the WDS server is running correctly but I am not able to see ports 67, 68, 69, and 4011 as open, they are all closed. I have ensured that the Windows Firewall is off while I am troubleshooting but they are all still closed.

The weird thing is the ProxyDHCP error, I don't use DHCP option 60 as the DHCP and WDS/MDT/SCCM servers are two separate systems. Without options 60 enabled, it shouldn't be doing anything with ProxyDHCP?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking Program Files\Microsoft Configuration manager\Logs\SMSPXE.log which had an error recorded "Warning: Matching Processor Architecture Boot Image (0) not found".
I hadn't added the x86 image, even though the computer boots the AMD64 boot image it still required the x86 image to be distributed to the distribution point for it to boot anything.